Can elasticsearch aggregation flip one to many relationship?
what the collection in elasticsearch looks like:

A{ users[1,2,4] }
B{ users[2,3,4] }
C{ users[1,3] }

output I want to achieve:

1{events[A,C]}
2{ events[A,B] }
3{ events[B,C] }
4{ events[A,B] }


Can you please provide more details on how your index mapping is setup and what is your sample data ?

Nested terms aggregations help you
Mapping for my example
PUT /events_users
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "users": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}

Your data in documents
PUT /events_users/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"A","users":[1,2,4]}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"B","users":[2,3,4]}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"C","users":[1,3]}

Query with nested aggregations. The parent aggregation is by the user, the sibling aggregation is by the event name
GET /events_users/_search?filter_path=aggregations.by_users.buckets.key,aggregations.by_users.buckets.by_name.buckets
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "users"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Response
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_users" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "by_name" : {
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "A",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "C",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "by_name" : {
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "A",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "B",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 3,
          "by_name" : {
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "B",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "C",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 4,
          "by_name" : {
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "A",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "B",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

The outer key is a user. The inner key is an event name.
See also my answer
